# One word for “someone who learns from others' mistakes"

Tags: single-word-requests, adjectives

Please give me one word for "someone who learns from others' mistakes". The word has escaped me for a while now. I've tried *observant* but it's still not cutting it for me.

Comment: Perhaps *student*? Or *child*?

Answer (score 3):

A wise person follows the "path through time immemorial" learning from others'mistakes.

Comment: But that means *a lot more* that *just* "learning from others' mistakes", which is what the OP asked for.

Comment: It's difficult to answer such questions. Please refer to this http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/97456/a-word-or-phrase-for-someone-who-learns-from-their-mistakes

Comment: @Sweet72 refer ***to*** this :)

Answer (score 2):

In simple English, A person who learns from other's mistakes may be called wise person

Comment: @Aluna has already given the same answer. Please include your own information in an answer, not just repeating what has already been said.

Comment: I was going to respond *intelligent*, but this is an even better phrase.

Comment: In **plain** English, **a** person who learns from **other people's** mistakes may be called a *wise* person.

Comment: @mikhailcazi Oh, the irony of not learning from someone else's mistakes when trying to describe the right word for learning from someone else's mistakes.

Comment: @JackRyan I lol'd! xD

Answer (score 2):

I can think of the following:

*fast learner* or *quick learner*

***sagacious***

***assimilator*** (as in one who absorbs new experiences)

Of course one would have to provide the context to fully establish the meaning. But I think that the situation described is too specific for a totally apt single word.

Answer (score 1):

**Circumspect** has the primary meaning cautious (bordering perhaps on over-cautious), but probably still connotes 'weighing up what's happening around oneself' - perhaps close enough to 'learning from others' mistakes'. There's no agent noun.